# Node Kue - Consume calculation on separate server

Tags: python, node.js, express, kue

I need to perform some 'heavy' calculations based on input files uploaded to my node/express server by users and restrict the number of calculations run simultaneously. The calculations are done by a Fortran 90 program (30-90 min running time).

I have been looking at Kue (https://github.com/LearnBoost/kue) to create the job queue, but I am somewhat confused on what can be done:

- Can i have a separate server running the calculations, starting the calculations with a e.g. python program (and then how to "get" the jobs?)? Or should i run a node server and then start a child process with the calculations?